# How to print a nested python list in columns

Tags: python, list, desktop

I have a program that produces a python list as its output the list is a nested list: A list of the list [name, address, phone number] which I wish to be able to print in a columnar format. It seems upon stating the question to be a very simple Idea, but I have been unable to find a simple way to extract the data from the list. If I print(list), I get something like this: ['name','address','phone number'], etc. for each item in the list. I'm using Python 3 on a windows platform.
Note: I am not a OOP programmer(at this point)

Regards Bill

Comment: I am very appreciative of all your answers, if there is a proper way to let each of you know of the solution I put together from your answers please reply...                                                                for name,area,phone in phonelist:
       print ("%20s %20s %20s" % (name, area, phone))

Answer (score 2):

Iterate over the list like this:

```
for name,add,num in lis:
   print (name,add,num)
```

**Demo:**

```
>>> lis = [['name','address','phone number']]
>>> for name,add,num in lis:
...        print (name,add,num)
...     
name address phone number
```

You can also use [string formatting](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#formatspec) for a better looking output:

```
>>> lis = [['name','address','phone number']]
>>> for name,add,num in lis:
       print ("{:<10}{:^20}{:^10}".format(name,add,num))
...     
name            address        phone number
```

Answer (score 2):

[`prettytable`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PrettyTable) can produce very nice looking ASCII tables. Example from the [tutorial](http://code.google.com/p/prettytable/source/browse/wiki/Tutorial.wiki):

```
from prettytable import PrettyTable

x = PrettyTable(["City name", "Area", "Population", "Annual Rainfall"])
x.align["City name"] = "l" # Left align city names
x.add_row(["Adelaide",1295, 1158259, 600.5])
x.add_row(["Brisbane",5905, 1857594, 1146.4])
x.add_row(["Darwin", 112, 120900, 1714.7])
x.add_row(["Hobart", 1357, 205556, 619.5])
x.add_row(["Sydney", 2058, 4336374, 1214.8])
x.add_row(["Melbourne", 1566, 3806092, 646.9])
x.add_row(["Perth", 5386, 1554769, 869.4])
print x
```

Should print something like this

```
+-----------+------+------------+-----------------+
| City name | Area | Population | Annual Rainfall |
+-----------+------+------------+-----------------+
| Adelaide  | 1295 |  1158259   |      600.5      |
| Brisbane  | 5905 |  1857594   |      1146.4     |
| Darwin    | 112  |   120900   |      1714.7     |
| Hobart    | 1357 |   205556   |      619.5      |
| Sydney    | 2058 |  4336374   |      1214.8     |
| Melbourne | 1566 |  3806092   |      646.9      |
| Perth     | 5386 |  1554769   |      869.4      |
+-----------+------+------------+-----------------+
```

Adapting this example for your use-case should be trivial.

Answer (score 1):

```
for name, address, phone_number in a_list:
    print '{}\t{}\t{}'.format(name, address, phone_number)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the print statement, for instance if you want all you fields to be 20 characters wide:

```
for e in list:
    name, address, phone = e
    print "%20s %20s %20s" % (name, address, phone)
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answers given will truncate your records if they go over the field size. If you want them to wrap instead, you need to use the [textwrap](http://docs.python.org/2/library/textwrap.html) module.

```
import textwrap
import itertools

col_width = 20

header = ["Name", "Address", "Phone Number"]

def columnar_record(record):
    columns = (textwrap.wrap(item, col_width) for item in record)
    line_tuples = itertools.zip_longest(*columns, fillvalue="")
    lines = ("".join(item.ljust(col_width) for item in line_tuple)
             for line_tuple in line_tuples)
    return "\n".join(lines)

def print_columns(records):
    print(columnar_record(header))
    for record in records:
        print(columnar_record(record))

a = ["Bill Bradley", "123 North Main St., Anytown, NY 12345", "800-867-5309"]
b = ["John Doe", "800 South Main Street, Othertown, CA 95112", "510-555-5555"]

print_columns([a, b])
```